SSH ignores ed25519 key and keeps asking password
I'm having trouble using the ed25519 keys to establish SSH connections.
I'm using three different machines: one server (A) and two clients (B and C).
A: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on VPS - OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
B: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on my laptop - OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
C Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on RaspberryPi 5 - OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
I generated two different ed25519 keys for B and C (on the related machines) and copied them both into authorized_keys in A. Additionally, running the ssh-keygen, I set the names of keyfiles on machine B and C to non-default names (~/.ssh/Aserver and ~/.ssh/Aserver.pub).
When I try to establish an SSH connection from B to A, everything works fine, and I don't need to enter any password. However, if I do the same from C to A, the key seems to be ignored, and I need to enter the password every time. The connection C-A works fine when established, but my problem is that I want to use the key and avoid typing the password.
I have checked the ~/.shh folder and file permissions, and there are no differences between B and C. The ssh_config files in /etc/ssh are also identical and reported below for convenience. I tried several keys, including the RSA version, but the final outcome is identical. Any idea about the possible cause of this issue?
Thanks!
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.d/%k
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes


EDIT:
The last part of the log obtained using the -v option when trying to establish the SSH connection from C to A is the following:
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive

The last part of the log reported above appears to be different from the one obtained during a successful connection from B to A, which carries on with further details of the established connection.

The log on A when trying to connect from B is:
2024-08-03T16:10:02.851654+00:00 ubuntu sshd[117315]: Connection closed by authenticating user root XXX.XXX.52.198 port 50746 [preauth]
2024-08-03T16:10:11.609279+00:00 ubuntu sshd[117323]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=XXX.XXX.0.22  user=root
2024-08-03T16:10:13.812878+00:00 ubuntu sshd[117318]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for root from XXX.XXX.0.22


Permissions for the key on C
-rw------- 1  978 Aug  2 18:38 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1  142 Aug  2 18:37 known_hosts.old
-rw------- 1  419 Aug  2 18:35 Aserver
-rw-r--r-- 1  106 Aug  2 18:35 Aserver.pub



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Apparently, the issue relates to the non-standard name assigned to the key when I generated it.
For some reason,(I believe) assigning a non-standard key name doesn't require any additional configuration for OpenSSH_8.9 clients, while it does for OpenSSH_8.6 clients.
The problem can be addressed by adding a line in /etc/ssh/ssh_config
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/theNameOfYourKey


Nice job figuring it out!
